# Moment of Inertia bounded by a parabola and line

Tags: integration, statics

[image]First time posting here but I'm struggling to find anything like this question online.
Top curve is a parabola:  $y= (1/44)x^2 +(21/44)x+8$ where a=10.5 in, b=8in, and L =32 in. I need to find $I_y$ and $I_x$. I think I understand $I_y$ using limits of 0 and 32 and the equation $I_y= x^2(1/44x^2+21/44x+8)dx$ if I lie it flat on the x-axis (can you do that?) Any help would be appreciated.
I'm totally bamboozled for the limits of the y-axis.

Comment: Why don’t you directly integrate the parabola from 0 to L and then subtract the triangle ?

Comment: When solving for Iy by using the the x^2da formula I get 365015.66 in so just subtracting the area of the triangle (128 in) seems a bit wrong. Unless I'm completely missing what you are saying. I'm struggling in this class but I'm sure that much is obvious.

Comment: You don't subtract the *area* of the triangle! You subtract the *inertia* of the triangle. Moments of Inertia taken about the same axis are additive. That is, if you have two objects A, B that you are rotating about an axis *l*, the combined inertia of rotating both objects around that axis is the sum of the inertias for rotating each separately. In your case, the inertia of the region below the parabola to the axis is sum of the inertias of the indicated region and of the triangle below it. You can calculate the inertia of the region down to the axis, and of the triangle, then subtract.